# Algorithms to Calculate Wasserstein Distance Between 2-Dimensional Continuous Probability Distributions

Tags: statistics, algorithms, optimal-transport, wasserstein

Say I've got two probability distributions $p_1(x,y)$ and $p_2(x,y)$ defined for all $x,y\in[-1,1]$, and now I want to calculate the Wasserstein distance between the two. Is there a closed-form formula or alternatively an algorithm to do it?